# Animate CC HTML5 attempting to change a global variable by calling a string

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scope, flash-cc

I am a veteran actionscript coder and am taking my first stabs at javascript. Mostly, it isn't too complicated, but I have run into some issues as I am creating a large number of buttons that are like toggles. Here is the code so far (I removed a bunch of them but, there will be about 20 of these, not just 5).

```
var aOneOn = false;
var aTwoOn = false;
var aThreeOn = false;
var aFourOn = false;
var aFiveOn = false;

this.One.addEventListener("click", highlightButton.bind(this));
this.Two.addEventListener("click", highlightButton.bind(this));
this.Three.addEventListener("click", highlightButton.bind(this));
this.Four.addEventListener("click", highlightButton.bind(this));
this.Five.addEventListener("click", highlightButton.bind(this));  


function highlightButton(event)
{
    console.log("You have selected a button " + event.currentTarget.name);  //Three
    var newName = "a" + event.currentTarget.name + "On";
    console.log("the buttons new name is " + newName); //aThreeOn
    console.log("the correct answer is " + aTwoOn); //false
    console.log("the button is currently " + this[newName]); //undefined
    if(this[newName] == true)
    {
        console.log("we should be turning it false now");
        this[newName] = false;
    }
    else if (this[newName] == false)
    {
        console.log("we should be turning it true now");
        this[newName] = true;
    }
    console.log("the button " + newName + " is now " + this[newName]);
}
```

This does not result in newName being able to actually access aTwoOn when the Two button is pressed, or any of the buttons functioning as I had hoped. I figure I am just missing something when it comes to the scope, but cannot seem to figure out what needs to be done.

Thanks for whatever help you can give to this noobie.

Comment: Can you describe what is happening?

Comment: Sure... In the game, the students will have a selection of 20 types of problems they need to practice that will be shown in 20 buttons. When they click on a button, it will highlight. If they click on it again, it will un-highlight. Then when they have selected everything they want to practice, they will hit the Done button. This part of the code is basically toggling the different options on and off. Once they hit done, it will go through and see which ones are on and add them to the list of problems. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @NatashaOliver `HTML` please

Comment: Sorry, it is all being done in Animate CC, so no HTML at this time.

Comment: Need to know what `event.currentTarget.name` is evaluating to. As that might be the root cause on why your code is not working.

Comment: edited to show what the console.logs print

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking it has something to do with the line

`var newName = "a" + event.currentTarget.name + "On";`

if `event.currentTarget.name` turns out to be `undefined`, then `newName` will evaluate to

`var newName = "aundefinedOn";`

And that might be the reason, it must be failing for your use case. Also it is a bit hard to say without looking at your `HTML`.

You can `add` or `remove` the class of the elements instead of modifying the state of the variable which keeps track if the button is toggled or not.

Also instead of binding events to each button separately you can have a common class and bind the event handler to the elements with the class.

**JS**

```
let toggleElems = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggleElems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("click", highlightButton);
});


function highlightButton(event) {
  let elem = event.target;
  console.log("You have selected a button " + event.currentTarget.name);
  var newName = "a" + elem.name + "On";
  var isOn = elem.classList.contains('on');

  if (isOn) {
    console.log("we should be turning it false now");
    elem.classList.remove('on');
  } else {
    console.log("we should be turning it true now");
    elem.classList.add('on');
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle" name="one">
  toggle 1
</div>
<div class="toggle" name="two">
  toggle 2
</div>
<div class="toggle" name="three">
  toggle 3
</div>
<div class="toggle" name="four">
  toggle 4
</div>
<div class="toggle" name="five">
  toggle 5
</div>
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5tLx5r5/1/)**

And to top it off, to find all the elements that are highlighted when you hit the done button you could just query with the active class again.

```
var highlightedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle.on');
```

Comment: While I am not sure I can do exactly what you suggested, I definitely see the benefits of creating the class and then just adding and removing the parameter. I will see if I can do that with just javascript in Animate CC.